# ejabberd 'make' through "cannot run compiled C program"

Tags: linux, gcc, centos, erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to install ejabberd on CentOS 6.x,When I run "make" command it gives me following errors.

```
ejabberd]# make
rm -rf deps/.got
rm -rf deps/.built
/usr/lib/erlang/bin/escript rebar get-deps && :> deps/.got
==> goldrush (get-deps)
==> lager (get-deps)
==> p1_utils (get-deps)
==> p1_cache_tab (get-deps)
==> p1_tls (get-deps)
==> p1_stringprep (get-deps)
==> p1_xml (get-deps)
==> p1_stun (get-deps)
==> esip (get-deps)
==> p1_yaml (get-deps)
==> jiffy (get-deps)
==> oauth2 (get-deps)
==> xmlrpc (get-deps)
==> p1_zlib (get-deps)
==> p1_iconv (get-deps)
==> rel (get-deps)
==> ejabberd (get-deps)
checking for gcc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/root/ejabberd/deps/p1_tls':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: Command ['get-deps'] failed!
make: *** [deps/.got] Error 1
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue? I have installed **Erlang-17.5** and all required "**development tool**" .Thank you.

Comment: It says `See config.log for more details`, does config.log show nothing useful? You could try `yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y` to make sure you have all the right packages, then try again. Run "make" NOT as root though (the build should not need or have root access), then you can run "make install" as root.

Comment: My guess is that you don't have a real C compiler installed, but rather only some default that can't compile real programs. Install gcc, then reconfigure.

Comment: @Michael - do you like to see my config.log file.?.I install all the "Development Tools" as you mention but it did not workout for me.

Comment: @Steve - I installed gcc. but how can I make sure that, it is real or not?

Comment: Try re-running configure. Where it says "checking for gcc" it should report finding gcc rather than cc.

Comment: @steve - you mean gcc is working fine or not?. I tried number of times to re-running configure. But I get the same error.

Comment: Where the configure output says "checking for gcc... cc" are you now seeing "checking for gcc... gcc" instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get this error, please make sure to install

```
 # yum install glibc-headers
```

This will solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

A gcc that works : `# yum install gcc-c++`

I.e. the install of the c++ compiler will also install the dependencies which will make gcc fully functional : glibc-devel, glibc-headers, kernel-headers.

Comment: I install separately glibc-headers. and it works for me.So that means     "# yum install gcc-c++"   wouldn't install the dependencies. By the way thank you very much. From your post I get the solution.